# AMD/AMD GPU Switching

Tags: 12.04, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I have two GPU's in my laptop, both of which are AMD.

Whenever I use the Catalyst Control Centre to change the GPU, nothing changes after reboot. In fact, when I do the `fglrxinfo` command the terminal only reports seeing one GPU, the integrated one (HD 4250).

The dedicated one (Mobility HD5470) goes unnoticed and I can't seem to use that GPU at all. I really don't want to use the Open Source drivers because I've found there generally slower than the proprietary, but the proprietary doesn't seem to work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've got a laptop with these two too. Even in windows I had to use vendor-specific driver for them to work. Installing catalyst from amd always breaks it. So far I haven't found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450 eventhough it's for AMD/Intel. Also this http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide has a lot of information in installing switchable graphics.
Hope it helps.

Comment: By the way, I'm running AMD/Intel hybrid graphics and when i run fglrxinfo I only see the AMD too nevertheless I can see both on the Catalyst Control Center so that might not be an error.